# Facebook registration plugin

Tags: facebook

does anyone have worked with the Facebook registration plugin?
+ http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

I'ld like to know if it's possible to create a username for my site with it like "example.com/users/username". 
Also can the entered data (custom data for my site) edited later or just by sign up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and Yes!

You can create a username and even check it before submitting the FB form, please refer to the [Facebook registration advanced document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/).

Also you should be storing the data returned by the Facebook plugin in your database! with that in mind, you (obviously) can edit these data.

I've written a tutorial a while back about [using the Facebook Registration Plugin](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-use-facebook-registration-plugin-as-your-registration-system/15/) that could help you too.